# How to set Password Type in C# while consuming a SOAP web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap-client

I am trying to consume a third-party SOAP web service in my C# console app. I tried two different way of passing the credentials as shown below.

```
//Method 1 - passing security credentials
myCardService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", 
"password");

//Method 2 - passing security credentials
System.Net.CredentialCache myCredentials = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
myCredentials.Add(new Uri(myCardService.Url), "Basic", netCred);
myCardService.Credentials = myCredentials;
```

In both the cases, I am getting this exception:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderExceptions: Error in SecurityHeader: An Invalid security token was provided

When I tried SOAP UI to consume the service, there also I got the same error. However, when I made WSS-Password Type = PasswordText in the Properties window of the tool, then it worked. I don't see any way to make this setting in the credential objects in the C# code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after I installed WSE 3.0 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14089 and changed the web reference manually from System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol to Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol in the Reference.cs file.

Comment: I have similar wsdl based webservice and have been used by Microsoft.Web.Services3 on VS2008 project. Upgraded project VS2008 to VS2017 and I did your suggestion but could not achieve SOAP request successfully. Getting always "Exception Details: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: com.wn.pve.platform.exception.PVEBusinessException" exception. Did you do anything else without your previous messaging content?

Comment: @umituzun84 did you find the solution for that issue?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding, that after you define your service binding to the authentication type.

```
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
```

After you have defined the authentication type, you would create your web service client and do the following:

```
client.ClientCredentials.Username.Username = networkCredential.Username;
client.ClientCredentials.Password.Password = networkCredential.Password;
```

That should be the appropriate manner to pass those credentials.

Comment: Greg, I don't see the binding or client options. I have created a web reference in my Visual Studio 2017 project using the wsdl provided. Thanks

Comment: Once I have created a web reference, it creates Reference.cs file which has the MyCardService class. When I instantiate it as "MyCardService myCardService = new MyCardServcie();" all the endpoints are available to be used.